# CSS Animation effect with flexbox with large content not working

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I tried to create the flexbox collapsible menu using HTML,css and angularjs the collapsible menu functionality working fine but the css transition effect not working when the content are big(ex: with "Lorem Ipsum" text block) its working fine when the "Lorem Ipsum" text block are not there, I couldn't find out the reason for the same. Thanks in advance for the help.

[Plnkr Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/o1L5ItYtKmBND3tCGzc6?p=info)

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.toggle = function() {
    angular.element(document.querySelector('.sidebar')).toggleClass('isClosed');
    angular.element(document.querySelector('.hideButton')).toggleClass('isClosed');
    angular.element(document.querySelector('.sidebar ul.nav')).toggleClass('isClosed');
  }

})
```

```css
/*
    * ==== RESETS ====
    */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*
    * ==== IMPORTS ====
    */


/*
    * ==== STYLING ====
    */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: -apple-system, ".SFNSText-Regular", "San Francisco", "Roboto", "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.hideButton {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.hideButton a {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 2px;
}


/*
    * ==== SIDEBAR ====
    */

.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  flex-grow: auto;
  transition: all linear 0.3s;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.sidebar.isClosed {
  flex-grow: 0;
  border: none;
}

.sidebar ul.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.sidebar ul.nav.isClosed {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar ul.nav li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 2px 0;
}

.sidebar ul.nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 2px;
}

.sidebar ul.nav li a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.sidebar div {
  max-width: 180px;
}


/*
    * ==== CONTENT ====
    */

.content {
  min-height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 9;
  padding: 40px;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}


/*
    * ==== TOGGLE BUTTON ====
    */

a.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  /* position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      left: 10px;*/
  display: block;
}

a.button:before {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  content: "<";
  transition: content linear 1s;
}

.isClosed a.button::before {
  content: '>';
  transition: content linear 1s;
}


/*
    * ==== MEDIA QUERIES ====
    */

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 736px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .sidebar {
    min-height: 60px;
    max-height: 60px;
  }
  .sidebar ul.nav {
    padding: 20px;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .sidebar ul.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2%;
  }
  .content {
    /*TBD*/
  }
  .content a.button {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="4.0.0" src="script.ts"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="4.0.0" src="system.config.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="4.0.0" src="tsconfig.json"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myctrl">

  <div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">

    <div id="aside" class="sidebar">
      <div>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Experience is the key of the item of the rest of the kind</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Bio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Aside -->
    <div class="hideButton">
      <div class="Aligner">
        <a class="button" ng-click="toggle()"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="content">
      <h1>Flexbox Off-Canvas Side Menu</h1>
      <h2>Easy to use</h2>
      <div>
        What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
        specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
        recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The
        point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem
        Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). Where
        does it come from? Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College
        in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and
        1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in
        their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Where can I get some? There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by
        injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators
        on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which
        looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /Content -->

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="4.0.0" src="script.ts"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="4.0.0" src="system.config.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="4.0.0" src="tsconfig.json"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="myctrl">

    <div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">

      <div id="aside" class="sidebar">
        <div>
          <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Experience is the key of the item of the rest of the kind</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /Aside -->
      <div class="hideButton">
        <div class="Aligner">
          <a class="button" ng-click="toggle()"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="content" class="content">
        <h1>Flexbox Off-Canvas Side Menu</h1>
        <h2>Easy to use</h2>
        <div>
          What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
          specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
          more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.
          The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use
          Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
          Where does it come from? Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney
          College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections
          1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum
          dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced
          in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Where can I get some? There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form,
          by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators
          on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum
          which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- /Content -->

    </div>
  </body>

</html>

/*
    * ==== RESETS ====
    */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*
    * ==== IMPORTS ====
    */

/*
    * ==== STYLING ====
    */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: -apple-system, ".SFNSText-Regular", "San Francisco", "Roboto", "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.hideButton {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.hideButton a {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/*
    * ==== SIDEBAR ====
    */

.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  flex-grow: auto;
  transition: all linear 5s;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.sidebar.isClosed {
  flex-grow: 0;
  border: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.sidebar ul.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all linear 5s;
}

.sidebar ul.nav.isClosed li {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar ul.nav li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 2px 0;
  transition: all linear 5s;
}

.sidebar ul.nav li a {
  display: block;
  opacity:1;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 2px;
  transition: all linear 5s;
}

.sidebar ul.nav.isClosed li a{
  display:none;
  opacity:0;
}

.sidebar ul.nav li a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.sidebar div {
  max-width: 180px;
}

/*
    * ==== CONTENT ====
    */

.content {
  min-height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 9;
  padding: 40px;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: transform 5s;
}

/*
    * ==== TOGGLE BUTTON ====
    */

a.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  /* position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      left: 10px;*/
  display: block;
}

a.button:before {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  content: "<";
  transition: content linear 1s;
}

.isClosed a.button::before {
  content: '>';
  transition: content linear 1s;
}

/*
    * ==== MEDIA QUERIES ====
    */

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 736px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .sidebar {
    min-height: 60px;
    max-height: 60px;
  }
  .sidebar ul.nav {
    padding: 20px;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .sidebar ul.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2%;
  }
  .content {
    /*TBD*/
  }
  .content a.button {
    display: none;
  }
}

var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.toggle = function() {
    angular.element(document.querySelector('.sidebar')).toggleClass('isClosed');
    angular.element(document.querySelector('.hideButton')).toggleClass('isClosed');
    angular.element(document.querySelector('.sidebar ul.nav')).toggleClass('isClosed');
  }

})
```